# trigger error with null output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, triggers

here is my trigger:

```
create trigger wyplacamy before insert on `skladki_wyplaty`
for each row
BEGIN
  SELECT p.wysokosc_skladki, p.ilosc_miesiecy INTO @wysokosc_skladki, @ilosc_miesiecy
    FROM skladki_aktualne p
    WHERE p.pesel = NEW.pesel AND p.id_ubezpieczenia = NEW.id_ubezpieczenia;

  SET NEW.wyoskosc_wyplaty = @wysokosc_skladki / @ilosc_miesiecy *75;
END
$$
```

This works, but the iutpput of "wyoskosc_wyplaty" is NULL, even wysokosc_skladki = 8000, and ilosc_miesiecy = 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables before using them.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger wyplacamy before insert on `skladki_wyplaty`
for each row
BEGIN

  DECLARE var_wysokosc_skladki INT;
  DECLARE var_ilosc_miesiecy INT; 

  SELECT p.wysokosc_skladki, p.ilosc_miesiecy INTO var_wysokosc_skladki, var_ilosc_miesiecy
  FROM skladki_aktualne p
  WHERE p.pesel = NEW.pesel 
  AND p.id_ubezpieczenia = NEW.id_ubezpieczenia;

  SET NEW.wyoskosc_wyplaty = var_wysokosc_skladki / var_ilosc_miesiecy * 75;

END
$$
```